# Can't add .tsx files to Node.js Web Application project

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, reactjs

I created a new *Blank Node.js Web Application* in Visual Studio 2015, and I'm unable to add `.tsx` files to my project and compile them. When I do so, the created `.tsx` file is put into a Virtual Project instead, even though it is present in the actual project as well. The project is set to compile `JSX` expressions as React calls.

It took me some time to track down what's happening behind the scenes, and what happens is that when a `.tsx` file is created in the project (through Add -> New File), it is created as a `Content` entry in the project's XML file, instead of a `TypeScriptCompile` entry. This is clearly an error.

I can fix the issue by manually editing the project's XML file, but no way I'm willing to do that for actual production in 2016, with hundreds of files.

**Step-by-step guide to reproduce the error**

1. Create a new *Blank Node.js Web Application* project
2. Create a new `.ts` file in the new project
3. Create a new `.tsx` file in the new project

See that the displayed "host project" of the `.tsx` file (check the top-left corner of the editor window) says "TypeScript/JavaScript Virtual Projects".

**How can I make it so that `.tsx` files are included in the project exactly how `.ts` files are?**

---

**Edit**

This is not a problem with a *HTML Application with TypeScript* project, but that project type contains a lot of unnecessary C# bloat that I don't need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can fix the issue by manually editing the project's XML file, but no way I'm willing to do that for actual production in 2016, with hundreds of files.

This has to do something with the project template, and is likely a bug. A possible workaround in the meantime is creating the new file as a `.ts` file, and *then* renaming it to `.tsx`.